# Fails to distribute my app: "Your app contains non-public API usage."

Tags: ios, iphone

After I fixed some bugs and refactored my project which has been release on App Store, it fails to distribute. The Xcode shows the following error message:

> - Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them, and resubmit your application.
> - The app references non-public symbols in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface

XXX is the app name.

I've search the entire project, and didn't find any this keyword (UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface). How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using any snapshot taking libraries in your project ? Check for Reveal.framework in your project

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Remove Reveal.framework from your project. This should not be linked in release mode of your binary.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I forgot to remove the Reveal pods.

Comment: OMG!! That would've taken me a bajillion years to remember that I had Reveal in my project. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Note that you don't need to remove Reveal.framework entirely if you are using CocoaPods. Use the following in your podfile: pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']

Answer (score 1):

You app contains code not only from sources, but from all statically linked libraries. You have to check all of those for containing private call. Looks like at least Reveal library contains it.

Answer (score 0):

**Double check any third-party libraries you are using in your project**

I was facing the issue and after checking my pods file, I found that [Look Back - Framwork](http://lookback.io) which is available for debug builds only as for as I know. So removing that fixed the issue. Successfully submitted app through Xcode 6.1 for Apple Testflight beta testing :)

Answer (score 0):

- Never ship an app linked against the Reveal library. Reveal exposes
  your app to deep introspection and will likely cause your app to be
  rejected by the Apple review team. Reveal is intended for internal
  development and debugging purposes only.
- The Reveal service will stop automatically while the iOS host app is
  not the frontmost app. It will automatically start again when the app
  is re-opened.
- Reveal supports inspection of applications compiled against iOS 6 and
  later. The iOS Deployment Target build setting must also be 'iOS 6.0'
  or later. You may see link errors if this is not the case.
- Reveal uses Bonjour to connect with the running iOS application. If
  you are running the iOS application on a device, it will need to be
  on the same network as the Reveal Mac app to be able to connect with
  it. If you have any problems connecting to your application check
  your firewall and proxy setting to ensure they are not blocking
  communications.

[Find out more...](http://support.revealapp.com/kb/getting-started/integrating-reveal-with-your-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

**cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview**

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.1.0**