# Your app contains non-public API usage - submit app

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an application to Itunes connect with XCode. I get this:

Your app contains non public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them and resubmit your application.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/myapp.app/setSoundsEnabled:

What should I do?

Comment: You used undocumented API calls. Be wary of copying and pasting off the Internet. You are only allowed to use methods that are listed in the official Apple documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fails to distribute my app: "Your app contains non-public API usage."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829521/fails-to-distribute-my-app-your-app-contains-non-public-api-usage)

Comment: Are you using setSoundsEnabled: in a class of your own?

Comment: yes I removed the setSoundsEnabled method and is ok now. How should I use this method without having this issue?

Comment: You don't and you enjoy the click sounds.

Comment: If you have a class with a method called setSoundsEnabled, you will be ok and your app will be published. When you upload your app sometimes it complains about methods with names matching private methods names, but the apps passes further apple validation. I know this because it happened to me.

Answer (score 5):

I got the similar issue once. These errors take place because of the old SDK of some third party frameworks that implements "setSoundsEnabled" method. In order to remove these errors, you need to follow the following steps:

1. Open the terminal window. Run the following command:

   ```
   cd (drag and drop your project folder here) Your_Project_Path
   ```

   Now, the current working directory will be your project folder.
2. Find all the SDK that uses "setSoundsEnabled" method using following commands:

   ```
   $ find . | grep -v .svn | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep setSoundsEnabled
   ```

   and

   ```
   grep -lr "setSoundsEnabled" * | grep -v .svn | grep -v .md
   ```
3. After getting the list of frameworks, search for the frameworks that **MATCHES** the query. Upgrade those frameworks.
4. Re-validate the app.

Answer (score 0):

Double check any third-party libraries you are using in your project

I was facing the issue and after checking my pods file, I found that [Look Back - Framwork](http://lookback.io) which is available for debug builds only as for as I know. So removing that fixed the issue. Successfully submitted app through Xcode 6.1 for Apple Testflight beta testing :)