# Non-public API usage on QT 5.9 iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, itunes, javascriptcore

I am using QT 5.9 and want to upload my game to AppStore but i got this email after upload
Received Message

```
Non-public API usage:
The app references non-public symbols in myGame: __ZN3WTF8pageSizeEv
```

I am using this in .pro file

```
CONFIG += c++11
QT += qml quick sql purchasing gui multimedia
```

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Do you know where this function is used/declared? Did you solved your other non-public symbols (see the edit history) yourself?

Comment: i removed all non used libraries from QT+=, i think Network, but not sure
, that error looks come from JavaScriptCore.framework,
i need it for Appodeal plugin

Comment: So, the problem is not related to Qt. You may consider specifying your new information in the body of your question. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340035/your-app-contains-non-public-api-usage-submit-app) may be useful.

Comment: i am not sure, will upload build without plugins to check it, and will back with the results

Comment: its not appodeal issue, i uploaded my project with out JavaScriptCore.framework and it processes well, and uploaded it with only JavaScriptCore.framework and give me same issue

Comment: Perhaps you're using an outdated version of the JavaScriptCore framework. The version that only supports iOS 10 doesn't have that problem IIRC.

Comment: @mohammadalabid did you find source of the problem?

Comment: not yet, i tried to contact apple, but not get any solution!
will back for it when i have some time

Comment: I just updated Qt to the new snapshot 5.10.0 and it works fine for iOS upload